# Paired t test or 2 sample t test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample, paired-data

I'm trying to test the hypothesis that there is no significant difference between the data below. I'm having trouble deciding whether I should use a paired sample t test or 2 sample t test. The sentence **"In the 1990’s a group of researchers reported the results of a study that
controlled for genetic and socioeconomic differences by examining 15 pairs
of monozygotic twins..."** is making me lean towards using a paired t test. Although I'm still quite unsure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself 'Is each twin with schizophrenia uniquely matched with a twin without schizophrenia?'. If the answer is 'yes' then the study design is paired, if 'no' then they are independent groups.